# Angular FormArray and Duplicates

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Do Angular  FormArray allow duplicates as its values.  Bcoz as i am seeing in my code formArrays is rejecting the repeated values and only taking unique once.If above is the case, what is the work around for this?

Comment: You should have a unique name for each control in the form array.

Comment: Could you add some code, to better describe your problem